# Connecting RoutedUICommand Namespace to WPF (VB.NET)

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am trying to create a custom CommandBinding, I've decided to put it into its own class so I may add more down the road.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Name="frmWPFtest" x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:self="clr-namespace:WPFtesting.CustomCommands"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFtesting"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WPF Testing" Height="800" Width="800" MinWidth="800" MinHeight="800">
<Window.CommandBindings>
 <CommandBinding Command="self:cmdExit" CanExecute="CommonCommandBinding_CanExecute" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

**Command Class**

```
Namespace CustomCommands

Public Class cCustCmds
    Public cmdExit As New RoutedUICommand("Exit", 
      "Exit", 
      GetType(MainWindow),
      New InputGestureCollection(New KeyGesture(Key.F4, ModifierKeys.Shift)))
End Class

End Namespace
```

When using `self:cmdExit` I get a `CommandConvertor cannot convert System.String` error, and when using `self:cCustCmds.cmdExit` I get a `Name "cCustCmds" does not exist in "WPFtesting.CustomCommands"`error.

Is there a specific way to make a class that contains Commands in VB? I have found literally no documentation for anything related to VB, all C#

Comment: Very few teams now use vb. Which is why all samples you'll find are c sharp. Don't use the approach you have there. Bind to an icommand public property in a viewmodel instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28081/How-to-place-all-WPF-commands-and-related-events-c), CommandBindings defined in XAML must point to methods which are defined in the MainWindow:

> The reason is, the current WPF version's XAML does not allow us to bind event handlers in this way. The event handlers must be defined in the code-behind file inside the MainWindow class. I don't know if this is a bug, an accidently left out feature, or if we are not even supposed to use this functionality, but this stops us from defining a centralized location for handling all commands' Executed and CanExecute events.

One option is to define the [CommandBindings in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.commandbindings?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub MainWindow_OnLoaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        Dim openCmdBinding As New CommandBinding(
            ApplicationCommands.Open, Sub(o, args) MyCommands.MyCommandExecute())

        Me.CommandBindings.Add(openCmdBinding)

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyCommands

    Public Shared Sub MyCommandExecute()
        MessageBox.Show("test")
    End Sub

End Class
```

With the following XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

We get the following result:

[image: WPF VB.NET CommandBindings]

Another option is what Andy is referencing in his comment:

1. Create a ViewModel for your Window.
2. Define Commands inside the ViewModel
3. Bind your Window's events into the commands.

For more information: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28738.using-icommand-with-mvvm-pattern.aspx

Comment: While this does work how I'd like it to, isn't this just overriding the regular `ApplicationCommands.Open` command? I suppose I'd have to point to an ICommand in order to truly create a custom command?